# EXCEL: How to sum different numbers in same cell?

Tags: excel-formula, sum, numbers, formula

[image: sum different numbers in same cell. Please click on for better understanding]

In excel sheet A1 column have values

```
234.56
234.6
124
12
```

I want a formula that will add them up to a total based on the numbers in column A2 like

A2=Sum of all the four numbers(234.56+234.6+124+12).

Anyone know how I can do this? Please let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you have FILTERXML:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s"))
```

[image]

Comment: FILTEREXCEL command not available in excel. How can i add that command in my excel file?

Comment: It is filterxml not filterexcel

Comment: Sorry, how to add FILTERXML function in my excel